# How do I create a dataframe from a colsum function

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have dataframe which I am trying to sum each column for a given condition. I am using the colsum function. Based on that result I would like to create a data frame.

See code

```
> colSums(Product.TRx[5:10])

2011-04 2011-05 2011-06 2011-07 2011-08 2011-09 2011-10 2011-11 2011-12  
      0       0   23318   21187   23933   22911   22600   23053   23467
```

Based on these results I would like to create a dataframe with the months(eg. 2010-11) as the column name and their corresponding values. I am going to add a new column called "Product"  and the value is 'AAAAAA' The dataframe should look like this

```
Product 2011-04 2011-05 2011-06 2011-07 2011-08 2011-09 2011-10 2011-11 2011-12  
AAAAAA      0       0   23318   21187   23933   22911   22600   23053   23467
```

How do I code this in R?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is a numeric matrix with column names, like this:

```
> m = matrix(1:12,3,4)
> colnames(m)=c("A","B","C","D")
```

Then do this:

```
> data.frame(Product="AAAA",t(colSums(m)))
  Product A  B  C  D
1    AAAA 6 15 24 33
```

If your thing is a data frame, it still works:

```
> md=data.frame(m)
> md$D = runif(3) # mix up some floats
> data.frame(Product="AAAA",t(colSums(md)))
  Product A  B  C        D
1    AAAA 6 15 24 1.285573
```

Comment: In case it's not a matrix and has mixed ints and floats: `data.frame(Product = "AAA", lapply(quakes, sum))`, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that your answer works, but colSums will coerce (which matters only in the special case I mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `as.data.frame` as such:

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(colSums(Product.TRx[5:10])))
```

And then add your extra column:

```
df$Product <- "AAAAAA"
```